# Deciding what textbook to read

Tags: coursework

I just enrolled in a CS course and the instructor gave a list of readings for the course. There is a total of 4 books and each book contains around 15+ chapters and around 2 thousand pages and all the chapters of the book cover our course syllabus. But I am now pretty confused about which book to read and how can I prepare for the course? All the books are somewhat similar but I have no Idea How to decide which book to read and How to read the book for the course.

Comment: What did your instructor say? I suppose they are in the best position to answer this question.

Comment: My instructor told me to utilize all the books because each book has a different kinds of explanations but he didn't show me How to read nor which book should I read for any particular topic

Comment: When it's time for the course evaluation, make a negative note that you did not receive proper guidance on the use of the (excessive) course literature.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Sorry, this seems absurd to me. We shouldn't encourage students to give into learned helplessness.

Comment: @Arno We're the educators! If we give excessive literature recommendations to students, it's our fault if the students are helpless, unless the university has a dedicated training for students on working with such excessive recommendations.

Comment: This seems like about $500 in cost for books. Is that correct?

Comment: My guess is that you are not expected to read those books to prepare for the course, but you read what parts are necessary for you to understand the material in lectures/assignments.

Comment: Are the books on reserve at the library? Go look through them and see which seem to fit you better (or some are better in some area than others).

Comment: @lighthousekeeper This is preposterous. No one ever explained to me that textbooks are not to be read from cover to cover. Now it is possible that in this case the instructor could have provided more guidance (since the asker is quite obviously inexperienced) but "utilize all the books" is fairly clear, if a bit tautological.

Comment: @Denis Nardin: My guess is that the list of books is for what I describe in the the first paragraph of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2772097/13130). Or it could be that the teacher intends to assign selected readings out of the books without any of the books actually being read cover-to-cover (which in some fields, such as math, is extremely rare). Or it could have been that the teacher is simply trying to [cover their bases](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cover+his+bases) for anything that might come up in class. The potential cost seems very problematic to me, however.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro: Hmm, I think that Denis Nardin was trying to make precisely the points that you also mention in your comments (that the books are obviously not intended to be read cover-to-cover, but rather in the way you describe it). By the way, what makes you think that the potential cost is problematic? I can't find information about this in the question.

Comment: @Jochen Glueck: I think you're correct, and it seems I didn't catch the intended meaning. (I'm assuming now that "ever explained" means something along the lines of "needed to explain".) As for the cost, at least in the U.S. that's been a major problem for STEM students in the past couple of decades (even longer, in fact), and for 4 books this could easily be $500 (as Buffy said). While the cost -- assuming it's very high -- may not be a concern for the OP, it's quite likely a concern for other students in the class.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro: Thanks for your response! I wasn't aware that textbooks are so expensive in the US (but admittedly, the books mentioned by the OP seem to be much larger than what I would expect from a typical textbook). I think I'll do some reading to understand this in more detail.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Yeah, sorry for not being clear. I wanted to say that no one ever felt the need to said that we were not required to read the ~6 textbooks listed in the syllabus cover to cover - it was considered self-evident that the main material were the lectures and the textbooks were for reference only. I guess maybe students coming from different backgrounds do not find this obvious? Maybe it's a mismatch between the professor's expectations (students should be able to self study) and what students are used to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It is ridiculous to assume there is anything of immediate value in a CS text.
> Instead, you should read all of Stack Overflow, where the real learning is at!

(just kidding)

They undoubtedly mean you should **treat the books as a reference to look up topics**, not read them cover-to-cover, as might be implied, and **may assign homework** from select topics amongst them.

I'd ask the professor to clarify whether they intend to assign specific homework assignments from the books and also ask them or your peers for more specific suggestions of relevant resources.

Frequently books in scientific topics have wildly varying (sometimes comically high) prices and often little correlation between price and printing age to quality.

Even though they're normally "off-topic" and eventually closed, the Stack Exchange network has dozens of threads of great books in a particular subject.

- [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)
- ...

I would also personally recommend if this is your first computer science course to approach books on the subject along the lines that most are broadly

- mathematically/theory-based and may deal with a very specific theoretical language that is not in common use, but very *elegant* for the field
  these tend to be extremely dense and unpleasant to understand at first, but enjoyable when you already have a good base and help with how to think about computer science and especially "formal logic" topics like lambda calculus
  Essentials of Programming Languages (Freidman, Wand, Haynes)
  [SICP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_and_Interpretation_of_Computer_Programs) (Scheme Lisp)
- deal with a particular language or subject (C, Python, C#, GNU/Linux, some particular database dialect) in-depth
  these tend to be great *references*, but nigh-impossible to read end-to-end because most of it is irrelevant outside of a niche situation and therefore boring and needless to subject oneself to
  Linux Programming Interface; Kerrisk
- largely tutorials for a particular language
  these tend to just be a collection of challenges and are best augmented by the above to help explain topics in greater detail
  Automate the Boring Stuff (free Python text) http://automatetheboringstuff.com/
  The Little Schemer (Scheme Lisp and Friedman (again))

Answer (score 13):

First, read a little bit from each book (which you borrowed from the library) and see which one you like best. Whose explanations work for you? Which book is working on the level of detail you prefer? If there is no clear cut winner, just pick one. You can also consider factors such as availability in your preferred format (e-book vs paper).

Once you have chosen your primary book, read it. If you come across a concept you struggle with, consider reading the relevant part of other books. Something seeing explanations from different perspectives can help. If the lectures bring up a concept not appearing in your primary book, look for it in the others.

Comment: Additionally, if you're in the US textbooks are expensive. Check with your campus library to see if they have copies of each textbook and read them there first before committing to buying one. Then if you want a second opinion on what an author said, you can always check out one of the other books later in the semester. My library stocked any book that was >$100, or was for a class with 300+ students (or some such numbers)

Comment: @RobinClower People buy textbooks???